# audiokit not working in latest update to Xcode

Tags: xcode, audiokit

I have updated *Xcode* today and audio kit is now throwing a exception.
I am using *pods* to install audio kit.

```
pod 'AudioKit'
```

is what I have inside the pod file.

I try to update the pod file but i have the latest audio kit.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community  -Thank you

Comment: I have to agree with @Momin - can you provide more information? I am guessing that you might need to check the Migration guide and see if there are any changes that apply to you in the new version: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/develop/Documentation/MigrationGuide.md

Comment: Hi guys @AureliusProchazka. Thanks for the Advice. First time i am Stack overflowing. 
I guess i was just looking for a update to Audiokit Pod  to address the change of Swift to latest swift. 
Will this be happening any time soon?

Comment: I had some odd behaviour when I updated a 4.1 project via CocoaPods to 4.2.1.  When I first updated, I was also getting a compiler error about the Swift version. I changed the pod to AudioKit 4.2, which I knew had no problem, and the error disappeared. Then I went back to 4.2.1 to confirm that was the issue . . . but the problem had disappeared.  I'm wondering if it is a CocoaPods/xcode issue.  4.2.1 is definitely working smoothly in that project for me now.

Comment: That is interesting, ill try change to 4.1 and see what happens. then back.

Comment: Ok all sorted. that did the trick. Took out the pod then re added it... all sorted now.